# Laravel Nova select the same value several times

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I use this package: https://github.com/ziffmedia/nova-select-plus

I need select the same values several times. How I can do it? I have a field:

```
SelectPlus::make(__('Products'), 'products', \App\Nova\Product::class)->rules('required')
        ->hideFromIndex(),
```

I tried use `->maxSelections(999)`, but it not working. Please help resolve this issue.

Comment: Looking at the source code of the package, it doesn't seem to support such functionality. Why do you need to select the same value multiple times, anyway?

Comment: @P.K.Tharindu for products, I need select same product for offer system.